# Удалить mutex из процесса запущенного моей программой

Tags: c#, winapi, mutex

Я запускаю процесс вот так:

```
var clientProcess = Process.Start("C:\\111\\111.exe");
```

Я нашел пример того что мне нужно в другом вопросе:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808831/delete-a-mutex-from-another-process
Но там используется DuplicateHandle, и mutex который нужно закрыть, закрывается в запущенном мной процессе, но появляется в моём приложении, как закрыть его полностью?

В итоге нашел немного корявое решение: отдельная программа, которая вызывает DuplicateHandle а потом закрывается.

Comment: «Я нашел пример того что мне нужно в другом вопросе» — а что вам нужно-то?

Comment: Нужно чтобы mutex совсем не было, а по этому примеру получается что хендл просто переходит на мой процесс. В идеале нужно понять как получить hObject мьютекса, и вызвать CloseMutex. Короче нужно чтобы можно было закрыть мьютекс как это делает ProcessExplorer

Comment: Подождите, а _для чего_ вам этот мьютекс? Какая ваша настоящая задача?

Comment: Настоящая задача, запускать из моего приложения другое, в нескольких экземплярах, но оно создает мьютекс чтобы не дать запустить больше одного.

Comment: Зачем вам hObject мьютекса с другого процесса? В каждого процесса своя таблица хендлов, и если вы получите чисельное значение из другого процесса, в вашем процессе он может указывать на другой ресурс или вообще никуда. А Process Explorer делает это через драйвер ядра, вы не сможете сделать тоже самое в обычном процессе.

Comment: Ну это какое-то нехорошее применение. Ну приаттачьте свой поток к другому процессу через CreateRemoteThread и делайте там, что хотите. Вам понадобятся серьёзные права, если то приложение защищается. Такие штуки проще делать из нативного кода, по идее.